# Best way to use 2.8" TFT as monitor panel for headless Pi?

Tags: python, pitft

I have the 2.8" tft installed on my Pi3. All working sucessfully.
I want to use it as a simple control panel for my headless Pi - which has wifi AP working and as well as Tor etc.

I want to see external IP on the display, then control things like Tor service, iptables etc but all in a simple headless mode.

I have played with pygames but don't find it very easy for this use.
Before I spend more time with pygames, is these a better way to do this? An easier way to show some details and allow a few simple interactions?

I also have the 4 tactile switches installed.

Comment: Please define "headless".

Comment: This question is extremely open ended. There must be about 101 ways to do this and then some more. You need to decide which programming language you want to use.. seems like you started with Python, I suggest you stick with. Just try with small steps. When you get frustrated, just leave it and come back tomorrow. Python will be the easiest way to go

Comment: Headless in the sense of no mouse or keyboard or console/screen. SSH access only. Python is the language I want to use. Is pygame the best way to interact with the TFT? What are some python-based examples of the other 101 ways that I should consider?

Comment: Asking for a *Best way* to do something is a pet peeve of stack exchange users, unless you clearly define what "best" means. Explain which issues you have encountered with pygames - that would make your question more specific and less hypothetical and calling for opinions.